# Texture Dispose Not Working in Three JS release 73

Tags: three.js

texture.dispose() doesn't seem to work in r73 but works fine in r75. What should I do to get it up and running on r73.

Comment: have you found any solution so far? why event listener is not working in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't either work in r77.

When using texture.dispose() the dispose normally should call onTextureDispose :

```
function onTextureDispose( event ) {

var texture = event.target;

texture.removeEventListener( 'dispose', onTextureDispose );

deallocateTexture( texture );

_infoMemory.textures --;

}
```

but it does not. Dont know if its a bug or something but in order to deallocate the texture I had to do a material.map.dispose() while I was clearing the scene (so to prepare for other texture to be inserted in the scene).

For example:

```
   var clearScene = function(){

    stopAnimate();

    if(scene && scene.children.length>0){

      for( var i = scene.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {

        if( scene.children[i] instanceof THREE.Sprite ){

          if( scene.children[i].material.map ) scene.children[i].material.map.dispose();

        }

        if( scene.children[i] instanceof THREE.Mesh ){

          if( scene.children[i].material.map ) scene.children[i].material.map.dispose();

        }

        scene.children[i].material.dispose();
        scene.remove(scene.children[i]);
        scene.children.splice(i,1);

      }

    }

  };
```

Note: by using just:

```
scene.children[i].material.dispose();
```

the Textures of a material don't get disposed according to the documentation. http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/Material

Hope that helps you.